# How to solve $AX+XB+CXC=D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I am currently trying to solve a convex minimization for l1-norm + TV-norm, and ends up with the following problem.
$$XA+BX+CXC=D$$
I am not sure whether there is a solution to this, or at least an approximation. I had read about Sylvester equation, but still unable to figure this out.

**[Details of the Problem]**

Consider the following minimization,
$$X_{k+1} = \arg\min_X ||X-X\phi_1||^2_F+||X-\phi_2X||^2_F+||\psi X\psi^T - Z||^2_F+\langle Y,\psi X\psi^T - Z\rangle$$

the first two terms are related to TV and the last two are from Lagrange. I did it through derivation, term-by-term and ends up with
$$0=X(I-ϕ_1-ϕ_1^T+ϕ_1 ϕ_1^T )+(I-ϕ_2^T-ϕ_2+ϕ_2^T ϕ_2 )X+(ψ^T ψXψ^T ψ - ψ^T Zψ)+ψ^T Y ψ$$
Hence, the problem roughly in a form of
$$XA+BX+CXC=D$$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let denote  $vec(X):=[x_{11},....,x_{1,n},x_{2,1},....,x_{2,n},...,x_{nm}]$.
Then $(A\otimes B) vec(X)=vec(
F)$
if and only if $BXA^T=F$.  Using this property of tensor product you can obtain that

$$(I\otimes A+B^T \otimes I+C^T\otimes C) vec(X) = vec(F).$$

It is pretty similar to solve the sylvester equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation